# How to use Google App Scripts to unfilter a pivot table?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, pivot-table

How to use GAS to clear a filter in a pivot table in Google Sheets?

For example, if there's a filter called "Car Name", the way to unfilter it in the UI is to click it and choose "Select all" (which will cause in this example also BMW to be checked).

So the only question is how to do the same programmatically (I assume via [getfilters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-table#getfilters))? Keep in mind there may be other filters, and only "Car Name" needs to be unfiltered.

In Excel VBA it would have been `ClearAllFilters` or `CurrentPage = "(All)"` i.e. `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Car Name").ClearAllFilters` or `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Car Name").CurrentPage = "(All)"`.

Sample input:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Car Name |
| 2 | Mercedes |
| 3 | BMW |
| 4 | Mazda |
| 5 | Porshe |

Then use a pivot on this input and filter out BMW:

[image: Select all]

You'll see it shows a number of what was filtered:

[image: Pivot filtered]

But if you click "Select all" suddenly the filter states "Showing all items", since everything is now checked:

[image: Unfiltered]

Sample code:

```
pivots(SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), "Car Name");

function pivots(sheet, filterName) {
  var pivotTable = sheet.getPivotTables()[0]; // first pivot table on sheet
  var pivotFilters = pivotTable.getFilters();

  for (var i = 0; i < pivotFilters.length; i++) {
     // Check if pivotFilters[i].something = filterName
     //    Then unfilter it
     //    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm hunching that the easiest way of unfiltering a pivot filter is by using [setFilterCriteria](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-filter#setfiltercriteriafiltercriteria) method. You'll need to create a new criteria that would select all of the data in your pivot table then set it as the new criteria for your filter using that method.

Answer (score 1):

That was a tough one! My dataset is almost 80K values, so function speed is a factor. After struggling I came up with a method that:

1. If there is a pivot table, gets the pivot's source data's first row (i.e. headers).
2. If the pivot table has filters, grabs them.
3. Grab's the pivot table's source data.
4. In the source data, grabs the column number from the first row based on its name.
5. Finds the right filter by its column number (since pivots can't return names).
6. Grabs all of the filter's column's original values.
7. Compares if `getVisibleValues().length` has less length than the array of the filter's original values. This also considers if there are blank values or not.
8. If so, sets the criteria to show all original values (including blank values due to next note).

Step 4 could be done in 2 ways:

1. By utilizing the sheet function `=UNIQUE(column2:column)` to get the column's unique values. This requires converting the column's number to a letter. In order to hide it from users I create a dummy sheet, hide it, run the function, grab its results, then delete the sheet and add a blank item (since unique doesn't include blanks I have to add them even if the original filter had no blanks). But overall it measured **2** seconds.
2. By grabbing the values right through GAS itself (and remove duplicates), but it measured **18** seconds.

<del>[SputnikDrunk2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76077524/4829915)</del> didn't work for me (possibly due to using multiple filters) - it changed my filter to grab only 1 values called `(Blank)`, and measured **19** seconds.

```
pivots(SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), "Car Name");

function pivots(sheet, filterName) {
  var pivotTable = sheet.getPivotTables();
  if (pivotTable.length === 0)
    return;
  else
    pivotTable = pivotTable[0]; // first pivot table on sheet
  var pivotFilters = pivotTable.getFilters();
  if (pivotFilters.length === 0)
    return;
  
  let dataRange = pivotTable.getSourceDataRange();
  let firstRowRange = dataRange.offset(0, 0, 1);
  let cell = firstRowRange.createTextFinder(filterName).findNext();
  if (!cell)
    return;
  let columnNumber = cell.getColumn();

  let filter = pivotFilters.find(filter => filter.getSourceDataColumn() === columnNumber);
  if (filter) {
      let uniqueValues = getUniqueValues(dataRange, columnNumber);
      var len_offset = (filter.getFilterCriteria().getVisibleValues()[0] == '' || filter.getFilterCriteria().getHiddenValues()[0] == '') ? 0 : 1;
      if (filter.getFilterCriteria().getVisibleValues().length < uniqueValues.length-len_offset) {
        let filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setVisibleValues(uniqueValues).build();
        filter.setFilterCriteria(filterCriteria);
      }
  }
}

function getUniqueValues(datarg, columnNumber) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hiddenSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("HiddenSheet");
  if (!hiddenSheet) {
    hiddenSheet = sheet.insertSheet("HiddenSheet");
    hiddenSheet.hideSheet();
  }
  var columnName = getColumnNameByNumber(columnNumber);
  var formula = "=UNIQUE('" + datarg.getSheet().getName() + "'!" + columnName + '2:' + columnName + ')';
  var cell = hiddenSheet.getRange("A1");
  cell.setFormula(formula);
  var uniqueValues = cell.getDataRegion().getValues().flat();
  sheet.deleteSheet(hiddenSheet);
  uniqueValues.unshift("");
  return uniqueValues;
}

function getColumnNameByNumber(columnNumber) {
  var columnLetter = "";
  while (columnNumber > 0) {
    var remainder = (columnNumber - 1) % 26;
    columnLetter = String.fromCharCode(65 + remainder) + columnLetter;
    columnNumber = (columnNumber - remainder - 1) / 26;
  }
  return columnLetter;
}
```

If you want not to use a sheet function and avoid the extra function `getColumnNameByNumber`, but suffer a **lot** more time time, then use:

```
function getUniqueValues(sourceDataRange, sourceDataColumn) {
  return (Array.from(new Set(sourceDataRange
    .offset(0, sourceDataColumn - 1, sourceDataRange.getNumRows(), 1)
    .getValues()
    .flat())));
}
```